# a makeActiveBinding definition fails to create JavaGD window

Tags: java, r

I use this line in my `Rprofile.site` (WindowsOS) to create a shorthand:

```
makeActiveBinding('newdev', function(...) {library(grDevices); dev.new(restoreConsole=T)},.GlobalEnv)
```

However, when I tried to execute it from the console in JavaGUI for R (aka JGR), it fails to create a window and returns `NULL` .  If I type `dev.new()` a new window opens just fine.  I've got JRE 1.7.0_06  installed and Java7 (everything is x64).

Then, I tried defining a new binding from the JGR console:

```
makeActiveBinding('newfoo', function(...) {library(grDevices); dev.new(restoreConsole=T)},.GlobalEnv)
```

That worked, in a sense -- it started creating graphics windows and wouldn't stop!
Any ideas?

thanks

Comment: I'd like to try this out, but JGR still doesn't work. Offtopic: you got JGR on x64 to work? Mine keeps complaining about jri.dll not found, did you have the same problem, and how did you solve it?

Comment: @ROLO  I loaded the latest Java and JSE from Oracle:  jdk-7u6-windows-x64  and chromeinstall-7u5, and all the requisite R-packages, and it "just worked."  jri.dll is in C:\Program Files\R\R-2.15.1\library\rJava\jri\x64 and in C:\Program Files\R\R-2.15.1\library\rJava\jri .   Hope that helps.